# Chart.js data goes backwards when retroactively pushing datapoint from HTTP request using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, chart.js

I am trying to push these sets of bodyweight data from my http request where the GET request returns the below data

```
bodyweight:
    2020:
        11:
            06: {logId: 5, value: 70}
        12:
            17: {logId: 2, value: 82}
            ...
    2021:
        01:
            02: {logId: 9, value: 81.6}
            04: {logId: 13, value: 75.4}
            10: {logId: 10, value: 80}
            13: {logId: 11, value: 87}
            14: {logId: 12, value: 90}
            17: {logId: 14, value: 95}
            25: {logId: 15, value: 82}
```

From these data, datapoints 2021: 01: 02 and 2021: 01: 04 were added retrospectively, ie. the were added later than the 2nd/4th January of 2021.

The method used to add these data to the chart is as follows:

```
this.metricsHttpService.getTrackingMetrics(clientId).subscribe((res) => {
      if (res.metric.bodyweight) {
        for (const year in res.metric.bodyweight) {
          if (res.metric.bodyweight[year]) {
            for (const month in res.metric.bodyweight[year]) {
              if (res.metric.bodyweight[year][month]) {
                for (const date in res.metric.bodyweight[year][month]) {
                  if (res.metric.bodyweight[year][month][date]) {
                    this.onUpdateChart(year, month, date, res.metric.bodyweight[year][month][date].value);
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

As you can see, the datapoints of the 2nd and 4th of Jan 2021 are looped backwards, instead of displaying a line that goes chronologically. Any thoughts? Thank you very much; I'm still new to chart.js!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chartjs will draw the line based in the index of the item, so if the items you added as last are on the end of the array this is the right behaviour, to get the behaviour you want you will have to insert the values into the right place in the array